# How can I scale multiple readers on mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, microservices, distributed-computing

**Details of my system**

1. *Mongodb*: Each document represents a transaction. 
   Each transaction can be a Debit card transaction or a credit card transaction.
2. *TransactionReader*: Polls mongodb for transactions periodically, and puts each transaction into a rabbitmq with routing keys 'debit', 'credit'
3. *TransactionWorker*: Can be of two types [DebitCardWorker, CreditCardWorker]
   Multiple instances of DebitCardWorker, CreditCardWorker listen to the queue and consume transactions and process them. Since I am using rabbitmq no two workers (of same type) process the same transaction.

**My requirement:**
I want to have multiple instances of TransactionReaders pulling data from mongodb, but I do not want a transaction to be duplicated in the rabbitmq.

One solution:
Introduce new field to denote state of a document(like WAITING, PICKED, PROCESSED) and use mongodb's `findAndModify()` and achieve synchronization in code between multiple reader instances. So, two TransactionReader processes pick a document with `status:WAITING`. Both attempt to `findAndModify(status:WAITING; new_status: PICKED)` and only one of them succeeds and proceeds to mark `status:PROCESSED`.

**My Question:** Is there a technology or library that helps me in load sharing between multiple instances reading from mongodb?

Comment: Transactions are globally ordered?

Comment: Can you elaborate what 'globally ordered' means? As another info about system I would not mind older transactions being processed after newer transactions.

Comment: Your solution is simple and it works but it *pollutes* the transactions with processing specific fields. You could use another rabbitmq queue for the unprocessed transactions and the workers consume transactions from there. This gives you separation of concerns and automatic work retrying in case of failed transaction processing at a cost of a more complicated architecture (you have one more system).

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I agree the given solution pollutes the transactions with processing specific fields. And that is exactly what I did not like about it. 

But regarding the solution of using another rabbitmq, aren't we pushing the problem to one more level up. How do I run multiple instances of the process that writes transactions into the rabbitmq?

Comment: " How do I run multiple instances of the process that writes transactions into the rabbitmq?" - you write into rabbitmq from the same process that writes to the transactions collection